# IOS model class Case Study

Tags: ios, model-view-controller, model

If I want to develop a book library app, how many models and view controllers do I need?

Should it be:
- `Books` class - for the whole collections of catalogue(Just title and cover art link).
- `Book`  class - a more in depth individual book detail(synopsis, author, isbn,...).
- `Chapter` class - the chapter within the `Book` class.
- `Page` class - the pages ithin the `Chapter` class.

If the `Models` are designed as proposed above, how many `ViewControllers` are a OPTIMUM to manage the `Views`? I am not sure if there is absolute answer here, thus I thought it would be nice to make a case study.

I find the `Model` of the `MVC` overwhelming and interesting. So I want to discuss and understand from the master in normal scenario, how would they design and manage their `Model` class.

1. Should `Model` always being called at `AppDelegate`? Why not `ViewController` which is more specific? Draw from the example above, wouldn't it more optimum to call the `Page` model after we choose the `Book`? Rather than called everything in `AppDelegate`?

Please enlighten me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Models are ok. The number of ViewControllers you need at least is 4 now. One tableViewController for Books, one tableViewController for Books, one tableViewController for Chapters and one viewcontroller for Page.

If you see there are three repetitions of tableViewController, so you can customise them to have just one tableViewController. Pass in the correct array of items and it will display accordingly.

So the minimum is 2 ViewControllers.

EDIT:

not in Appdelegate definitely. in Viewcontroller, definitely. Write a separate ModelManager, which get the data from the tables. This modelmanager will pass the model information to the viewcontroller to display in view

Comment: Hi @lakesh what about when to call the model?? AppDelegate? ViewController?